# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Seemingly conflicting joins cause query to be very slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**This query takes 16 seconds to run**

```
SELECT 
    WO.orderid
FROM 
    WebOrder as WO
    INNER JOIN Addresses AS A ON WO.AddressID = A.AddressID
    LEFT JOIN SalesOrders as SO on SO.SO_Number = WO.SalesOrderID
```

**If I comment out either of the joins, it runs in a small fraction of a second. Example:**

```
SELECT 
    WO.orderid
FROM 
    WebOrder as WO
    INNER JOIN Addresses AS A ON WO.AddressID = A.AddressID
    -- LEFT JOIN SalesOrders as SO on SO.SO_Number = WO.SalesOrderID
```

or

```
SELECT 
    WO.orderid
FROM 
    WebOrder as WO
    -- INNER JOIN Addresses AS A ON WO.AddressID = A.AddressID
    LEFT JOIN SalesOrders as SO on SO.SO_Number = WO.SalesOrderID
```

**Notes**

- There exists about 40,000 records each in tables SalesOrders and Adddresses.
- I have indexes or PKeys on all fields used in the ON clauses.

**Execution Plan for the slow version (SalesOrders Join commented out)**

[image]

**Execution Plan for fast version**

[image]

**Why do these joins when used in conjunction with one another cause this to go from ~0.01 seconds to 16 seconds?**

Comment: Have you tried index rebuild, update stats and `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`?

Comment: Rebuilding the indexes in the involved tables fixed it. Please post as an answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. Answer is posted, as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your execution plan doesn't show any expensive operations, I would try to following to troubleshoot bad performance:

- Rebuild Indexes
- Update Stats
- `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`

Personally I wouldn't expect the latter to do anything -- it looks like you have a sensible query plan as it is.

Comment: Excellent answer. In my case, rebuilding the indexes for all tables involved did the trick. I did notice that the fragmentation value for one of the indexes was greater than 8.0.